# Overlay on a png doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm having a png and I just want to add a color overlay. I tried this as follows:

```
    Drawable icon= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_nav_heart_outline);
icon.mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.citylifeapp_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 42, 42, true));
        btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null, null, null);
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Does someone know the problem?

EDIT:

Image from the button for clarification:

[image]
[image]

Comment: add it using framelayout

Comment: if you are adding image via layout then you can add your overlay using frame layout easily

Comment: But then the overlay is all over the button and I just want it over the drawable thats on the left of the button.

Comment: can you add an image for clarification

Comment: Added the two states of the button. It's a button with padding and a left drawable.

Comment: for this thing I think you have to use two images